# React triggering full life-cycle when props children submitted outside render method

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state, react-lifecycle

I have a situation where I need the components of my application to render in one of two states based on a user click of a button. The problem I am having is that React triggers the full life-cycle of these components, even though all I am changing is the state/props of the components. I am using React 15.6, due to legacy limitations (this app is actually backbone with react embedded), also I cannot use JSX.

props.viewMode === 'ux' || 'dnd' (based on the user button clicks)

Here is the relevant code:

```
      render() {
        return this[this.props.viewMode]();
      }

      ux: function() {
        return React.createElement(
          "div",
          {
            "id":         this.props.node.type,
            "name":       this.props.node.component
          },
          **this.props.children**
        );  
      },

      dnd: function() {
        return React.createElement(
          "div",
          {
            "id":         this.props.node.type,
            "name":       this.props.node.component
          },
          return React.createElement(
            "div",
            {
              "id":         this.props.node.type,
              "name":       this.props.node.component
            },
            **this.props.children**
          )
        );  
      },
```

When this code is run, it triggers the getInitialState() method in the children, even though the only thing that changes is the viewMode, which is passed down as props from the highest order component down the chain to the child components.

It seems that any reference to props.children outside of the render() method triggers a full life-cycle, destroying the component and creating a new one.

If I refactor the code like this:

```
      render() {
        const children = this.props.children.sort((a, b) => { return a.order > b.order });
        const elem     = this[this.props.viewMode]();

        //assign children to elem, e.g. elem.props.children = children;

        return elem;
      }

      ux: function() {
        return React.createElement(
          "div",
          {
            "id":         this.props.node.type,
            "name":       this.props.node.component
          },
          **null**
        );  
      },

      dnd: function() {
        return React.createElement(
          "div",
          {
            "id":         this.props.node.type,
            "name":       this.props.node.component
          },
          return React.createElement(
            "div",
            {
              "id":         this.props.node.type,
              "name":       this.props.node.component
            },
            **null**
          )
        );  
      },
```

React does not trigger the getInitialState() method in the children.

Does anyone know why this would be? What am I missing?

Comment: After more digging it seems the problem is different from what I originally stated. Assigning the children to the element also does cause the full lifecycle to trigger. Is there anyway to format this so that I can change the viewMode prop at the very top of the component hierarchy and have it roll down without destroying and recreating each component, while using children.

Comment: Also note that I am using a nested JSON structure with children of children in order to generate the components, and a recusrive rendering function that passes children of children in until the end of the nested JSON.